# intagrate fosUserBundle`s table in Sonata

Tags: mysql, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I used FOSUserBundle and now install SonataAdmin and want to intagrate their.
I find SonataUserBundle and now, when I installed bundle, I have problem with MySQL, i have table 'fos_user', but now, SonataUser try to find 'sonata_user_user' table.
can I do something to override this search and work this my table.

## app/config/config.yml

```
sonata_user:
#security_acl: true
manager_type: orm
class:                  # Entity Classes
    user:               AppBundle\Entity\User

fos_user:
db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
firewall_name: main
user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
registration:
    form:
        type: app_bundle_user_registration
profile:
    form:
          type: app_bundle_profile
          handler: app_bundle.form.handler.profile

group:
    group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
    group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager                    # If you're using doctrine orm (use sonata.user.mongodb.user_manager for mongodb)

service:
    user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
```

## app/config/parameters.yml

```
sonata.user.admin.user.entity: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

## app/config/security.yml

```
security:
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

#acl:
 #   connection: default

firewalls:
    admin:
        pattern: /admin(.*)
        context: user
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: /admin/login
            use_forward: false
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            failure_path: null
        logout:
            path: /admin/logout
        anonymous: true
    main:
        pattern: .*
        context: user
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: /login
            use_forward: false
            check_path: /login_check
            failure_path: null
        logout: true
        anonymous: true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    SONATA:
        - ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT
```

I'll show all code what U need. Thanks!!

EDIT

Sorry, understood!

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the documentation [*User bundle installation*](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html) then sonata tells to extend its core user bundle through [*EASYEXTENDS BUNDLE*](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends) once you have generated its child bundle ([*reference*](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html#extending-the-bundle)) commonly generates in `src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle` sonata also generates the `orm` file in `src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Resources/config/doctrine` depending upon your database type like `User.orm.xml` or `User.mongodb.xml` in this file you can define your table name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                  http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <entity name="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User" table="fos user table name here">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```